# Copy selected columns and insert to another csv using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a two csv files. Both have same number of columns but not in row. I would like to copy 3 columns from csv1 and merge into csv2 using powershell.

I am not good at scripting. Could someone help me?
Here is code I am using.

$csv1 = Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\BackUp\PScripts\SDO\Report.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\BackUp\PScripts\SDO\7Saturday9PM.csv

$Results = @()
foreach ($record in $csv2) {
    Add-Member -InputObject $record -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FoundInAD -Value $($csv1 | ? { $_.InstalledOrNA -eq $record.InstalledOrNA } | select -Property FoundInAD)
    $Results += $record
}

$Results | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,PatchingStyle,LastSyncTime,LastSyncResult,LastReportedStatusTime,PendingReboot,NeededCount,InstalledOrNA,FoundInAD

Comment: Please do not show your example csv files as a link to an image. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61226205/edit) your question and insert the sanitized files as [formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189). Also provide info about what you have tried already (insert the code) and what the desired output should look like.

Comment: How to add an inline image.  Copy and paste in the body

Comment: You want to copy "foundinAD, results, and Uptime" from csv1 to csv2? What was used to create csv1?  Why don't you copy the code that was used to create the three columns in csv1 and paste it into the code that created csv2?

Comment: @somebadhat yes that was am trying to do, sorry am just new here and just a beginner the csv1 was from a wsus report using a powershell the csv2 was from another powershell script to test-connection the devices from wsus if it still active and exist in AD.